# Getting a number in a range using math

Tags: c++, math

Is there a way to take a number and using some math, have it be transformed to a range between two numbers, like [LB,UB].  I know I can do something like `x = x % UB` to get a number between `0-UB`.  But how do I get it so it is between LB-UB. I tried `x = (x % UB) + LB` but I can't figure out how to assure that x wont be over UB once I add LB.

Comment: `Num % (UB - LB) + LB`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about `(x % (UB-LB)) + LB`

You just get the mod of the range and move the number by the lower bound.

Note that you may need to add one to the range `(UB-LB+1)` if its inclusive. ie with the above formula if LB = 10 and UB = 20, you would get numbers from 10 to 19 inclusive. This is the way the regular mod would work.

For the closed range [LB, UB] you would just add 1 to the mod range:

`(x % (UB-LB+1)) + LB`

Comment: You'll need to add one to the modulus to get a closed range as specified in the question. (Or change the specification to a semi-open range, which will be less of a headache for C++ programmers).

Comment: Updated answer to reflect both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
x = (x % (UB - LB +1)) + LB
```

What you do is that you measure the interval you want to get your number in `(UB - LB + 1)` or forget the `+1` if you don't want to get UB out. This is the number of options you have. Then add `LB` so that he result is in the right range.

This works even for negative numbers, as long as UB > LB.

Answer (score 0):

this will work

```
x = x % (UB - LB) + LB
```